# MySQL Query self Join for Max date

Tags: mysql, date, join, max

I have 2 tables, contact and search. 'Contact' has the contact's id and companyid where he works at.
'Search' has the contactid and the companyid he belongs to cos' a contact can work at 2 companies. It also has the last time a contact searched the database. cityid corresponds to the city he worked in.

I am looking for every uniquely identified contact's lastsearchdate. How do I get the desired output?

```
create table contact (id integer primary key auto_increment, companyid integer, contactid integer, unique key(companyid, contactid));
insert into contact (companyid, contactid) values (1,1), (1,2), (2,3);
```

contact:

```
id companyid contactid
1  1         1    
2  1         2
3  2         3

create table search (searchid integer primary key auto_increment, companyid integer, contactid integer, cityid integer, lastsearchdate date);
insert into search (companyid, contactid, cityid, lastsearchdate) values (1,1,1,'2012-03-01'), (1,1,2,'2012-04-16'), (2,3,3,'2012-04-01'), (1,1,1,'2012-03-07'), (2,3,4,'2012-04-10'), (1,2,1,'2012-04-01');
```

search:

```
searchid companyid contactid cityid   lastsearchdate
1        1          1        1        2012-03-01
2        1          1        2        2012-04-16
3        2          3        3        2012-04-01
4        1          1        1        2012-03-07
5        2          3        4        2012-04-10
6        1          2        1        2012-04-01
```

Desired output :

```
companyid contactid cityid lastsearchdate
1         1         2       2012-04-16
1         2         1       2012-04-01
2         3         4       2012-04-10
```

Query so far :

```
select b.companyid, b.contactid, a.cityid, a.lastsearchdate from search a join contact b
on a.companyid = b.companyid and a.contactid = b.contactid
join search c
on a.companyid = c.companyid and a.contactid = c.contactid and a.lastsearchdate > c.lastsearchdate
group by b.companyid, b.contactid;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the description of what you are looking for, wouldn't this be the desired output from you sample data? (not sure why you also discarded records 2 and 3 from below)

```
companyid contactid cityid   lastsearchdate    
1          1        2        2012-04-16
2          3        3        2012-04-01
1          1        1        2012-03-07
2          3        4        2012-04-10
1          2        1        2012-04-01
```

If this is correct, this query will work:

```
select t1.companyid, t1.contactid, t1.cityid, t1.lastsearchdate
from search t1
where t1.lastsearchdate = (select max(t2.lastsearchdate) from search t2 where t2.companyid =
t1.companyid and t2.contactid = t1.contactid and t2.cityid = t1.cityid);
```

Comment: Contacts are uniquely identified by the company they work at. So 1,1 and 2,3 shouldn't be appearing twice. 1,1 and 1,2 and 2,3 are the unique contacts.

Comment: adding group by t1.companyid, t1.contactid; is giving me the 3 unique records I am looking for but record 2,3 is not displaying the max date. Strange.

Comment: Ok, if cityid is not part of contact identifier, then removing the "and t2.cityid = t1.cityid" from the query provides the desired results.

Comment: It worked, thanks! How do we achieve this without using MAX, do you know?

Comment: Modify the subquery to following .... (select t2.lastsearchdate from search t2 where t2.companyid =
t1.companyid and t2.contactid = t1.contactid order by t2.lastsearchdate desc limit 1);